# Akka static usage

Tags: akka, akka-actor

I have a simple actor system with default configuration.

I have a class extended Actor

```
class Test extend Actor {
  def receive: Receive = {
      case Foo(collection) => sender ! extract(collection)
  }

  private def extract(c: List[FooItem]): List[BarItem] = ???
}
```

This actor have a companion object

```
object Test {
  def props: Props = ???
}
```

Is there are safe to do function extract like this:

```
object Test {
  def props: Props = ???
  def extract(c: List[FooItem]): List[BarItem] = ???
}
```

and use from another Actor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's ok to define a method on a companion and then import and use that method in an actor class.  Something like this would work just fine:

```
object Test {
  def props: Props = Props[Test]
  def extract(c: List[FooItem]): List[BarItem] = {
    . . .
  }
}

class Test extend Actor {
  import Test._
  def receive: Receive = {
    case Foo(collection) => sender ! extract(collection)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just worried about multithreading. Is there are some actor specific in this case.

Comment: The example shown—a pure function that does not depend on the actor—is fine to use this way.  You should *not* do this if you were, say, passing the `ActorContext` into the `extract` function.